# Set the trigger' name as the event action on Google Tag Manager

Tags: triggers, google-tag-manager

I would like to know how to set a variable on Tag Manager that gets the trigger name. The objective is use this Variable on the Event Action of the event tag, so later I will know on Analytics which trigger fired the event.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: Alas there is no such a thing. It would be difficult to implement, too, since at any point there might be multiple matching triggers, or the tag might not be fired despite one or more matching triggers (e.g. if there are blocking triggers).

Comment: Thanks Eike for answering! It is a pity to hear that.
In any case, if I have the same phone number in the home page but also in the footer. Would you use two tags to differentiate the event? Since now I always used the same tag but I never know which link is the best performing...